# Php MySql Query with Multiple Keyword for Multiple Fields

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am creating a web application using php and mySql.

It is basically a simple search form with a single textbox.

The user input can be a combination of keywords, for which I am using php `explode()` function, after `string_ireplace()`.

Now I want to search each keyword (say val 1, val 2, ..... val n) against each field (say filed 1, filed 2, ...... field n) in a single table.

I feel I will have to use multiple for loops- for each value search all fields.

But how can I sort the result according to relevance, ie. records that match all values will appear first and so on.

Since this table sorting is not at database level, I am not able to use `ORDER BY` clause.

EDIT: OK. I thought I must explain in detail what I am looking for and what I have achieved. The following code I have written, it almost serves my purpose, but looks quite time consuming(for execution).

```
<?php
//$str = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['searchText']);
$str = "val1, val2, val3";
$str = trim($str);

// check for an empty string and display a message.
if ($str == "") {
    $resultmsg =  "<p>Search Error: Please enter a search keyword...</p>" ;
}
    $str = explode(",",$str);
    //Create array for all fields
    $fields = array("filed1","filed2","filed3","filed4");
    $condition = "";

    for ($j=0;$j<count($str);$j++){
        for ($i=0;$i<count($fields);$i++){
            $condition = $condition.$fields[$i]." = '".$str[$j]."' OR ";            
        }
        $condition = rtrim($condition, " OR");
        $condition = $condition.") AND (";      
    }
    $condition = rtrim($condition, " AND (");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE (".$condition;
    echo $sql;
    echo "<br /><hr>";

    $condition = "";
    for ($j=0;$j<count($str);$j++){
        for ($i=0;$i<count($fields);$i++){
            $condition = $condition.$fields[$i]." = '%".$str[$j]."%' OR ";          
        }
        $condition = rtrim($condition, " OR");
        $condition = $condition.") AND (";      
    }
    $condition = rtrim($condition, " AND (");
    //$condition = str_replace("="," LIKE ",$condition);
    $sql= "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE (".$condition;
    echo $sql;
    echo "<br /><hr>";

    //testing
    if (count($str)==3){
    $condition = "";
    for ($j=0;$j<count($str)-1;$j++){
        for ($i=0;$i<count($fields);$i++){
            $condition = $condition.$fields[$i]." = '%".$str[$j]."%' OR ";          
        }
        $condition = rtrim($condition, " OR");
        $condition = $condition.") AND (";      
    }
    $condition = rtrim($condition, " AND (");
    //$condition = str_replace("="," LIKE ",$condition);
    $sql= "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE (".$condition;
    echo "<strong>Matching ".$str[0]." AND ".$str[1]."<br /></strong>";
    echo $sql;
    echo "<br /><hr>";
    $condition = "";
    for ($j=1;$j<count($str);$j++){
        for ($i=0;$i<count($fields);$i++){
            $condition = $condition.$fields[$i]." = '%".$str[$j]."%' OR ";          
        }
        $condition = rtrim($condition, " OR");
        $condition = $condition.") AND (";      
    }
    $condition = rtrim($condition, " AND (");
    //$condition = str_replace("="," LIKE ",$condition);
    $sql= "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE (".$condition;
    echo "<strong>Matching ".$str[1]." AND ".$str[2]."<br /></strong>";
    echo $sql;
    echo "<br /><hr>";
    $condition = "";
    for ($j=0;$j<count($str);$j=$j+2){
        for ($i=0;$i<count($fields);$i++){
            $condition = $condition.$fields[$i]." = '%".$str[$j]."%' OR ";          
        }
        $condition = rtrim($condition, " OR");
        $condition = $condition.") AND (";      
    }
    $condition = rtrim($condition, " AND (");
    //$condition = str_replace("="," LIKE ",$condition);
    $sql= "SELECT * FROM TABLE> WHERE (".$condition;
    echo "<strong>Matching ".$str[2]." AND ".$str[0]."<br /></strong>";
    echo $sql;
    echo "<br /><hr>";
    }

?>
```

The output I am getting is as follows:

**Matching all values EXACTLY**

SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE (filed1 = 'val1' OR filed2 = 'val1' OR filed3 = 'val1' OR filed4 = 'val1') AND (filed1 = ' val2' OR filed2 = ' val2' OR filed3 = ' val2' OR filed4 = ' val2') AND (filed1 = ' val3' OR filed2 = ' val3' OR filed3 = ' val3' OR filed4 = ' val3')

**Matching all values PARTIALLY**

SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE (filed1 = '%val1%' OR filed2 = '%val1%' OR filed3 = '%val1%' OR filed4 = '%val1%') AND (filed1 = '% val2%' OR filed2 = '% val2%' OR filed3 = '% val2%' OR filed4 = '% val2%') AND (filed1 = '% val3%' OR filed2 = '% val3%' OR filed3 = '% val3%' OR filed4 = '% val3%')

**Matching val1 AND val2**

SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE (filed1 = '%val1%' OR filed2 = '%val1%' OR filed3 = '%val1%' OR filed4 = '%val1%') AND (filed1 = '% val2%' OR filed2 = '% val2%' OR filed3 = '% val2%' OR filed4 = '% val2%')

**Matching val2 AND val3**

SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE (filed1 = '% val2%' OR filed2 = '% val2%' OR filed3 = '% val2%' OR filed4 = '% val2%') AND (filed1 = '% val3%' OR filed2 = '% val3%' OR filed3 = '% val3%' OR filed4 = '% val3%')

**Matching val3 AND val1**

SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE (filed1 = '%val1%' OR filed2 = '%val1%' OR filed3 = '%val1%' OR filed4 = '%val1%') AND (filed1 = '% val3%' OR filed2 = '% val3%' OR filed3 = '% val3%' OR filed4 = '% val3%')

I can now keep on appending the fetched data into my result table. But somehow I dont feel this is a smart solution. Moreover I have a restriction on number of search values(eg. 3 here). I hope I able to explain what exactly I am looking for.

Comment: Hoo boy, that's a tough one. I'm posting this as a comment, cuz it's not directly an answer to your question, but you may want to create a 'search keywords' table. It's [denormalised](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization), so you are duplicating data for the sake of optimisation. Questions though: 1. are you doing a LIKE search or an exact match? 2. As a corollary of 1, will there be only one keyword in each field, or will it be a collection of words separated by spaces/punctuation?

Comment: Yes I know this is difficult. For your Q1, does it really matter whether it is exact or LIKE. I will use a wild character and consider both as 1 occurrence, and for Q2 I will instruct user to use + sign to separate two keywords, for the sake of simplicity. I was thinking what if I use number of separate queries (equals to number of keywords) and then merge the results into a single table.

Comment: You have something in your mind, and you ask how it can be done, no problem so far. However without providing satisfing information and detailed accomping rules, I believe any answear given will have as a base your own frame-concept of mind, will be limited on a specific path due to lack of information.

Comment: @ArunavaDey My reason for asking the questions was that, if each field only holds one keyword, then you won't have to use LIKE, but if it holds more than one, you will. It'll certainly be fastest (in development time) to use a number of querieas and then compile the results in PHP, but it won't be very optimised. The fastest (in server time) is a separate search table... I'll wait for more info before I explain how a search table works though.

Comment: @Paul d'Aoust In my database each field only holds one keyword. So I don't feel I need to use LIKE.

Comment: @ArunavaDey Thanks for the info. You are correct; you don't need to use LIKE if there's only one keyword per field. I also edited your question so the original answer is there as well -- has to be reviewed before the changes will appear. (Hint: you can edit your question, use the 'Rev' selectbox near the top of the page, and get back a previous revision.)

Comment: It might be helpful for us to know exactly what sort of data you're putting into these fields; can you give us a real-world example? Is there any case where you might have the same keyword in each field; e.g., `field1 = 'mouse' and field2 = 'mouse' and field3 = 'mouse'`? Also, when you say that you have a restriction on number of search values, do you mean you _want_ to have a restriction, or your current code restricts users and you _don't_ want that restriction?

Comment: @Paul d'Aoust Thanks for your reply. For your Q!: Yes I may have same keyword in different fields. And for Q2: the resatriction is because of my code, which I don't want(in the test part of my code). I have used the condition if (count($str)==3), so that I can selectively omit keywords(last three query outputs). In reality I am working with a map catalog, where I have stored descriptions of a map, like theme, scale, price, language and etc. Now the user input could be "India+Rainfall+English". I want maps matching all these keywords to appear first and then "India + Rainfall" and so on

Comment: Ah, I see. Partial answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an answer, which deals with the issue of scalability (restriction on number of keywords that a user can search) and sorting in order of relevance (number of matched keywords per map). I've removed things like checking for empty values, but I've added a few things; read the comments to see what. Haven't tested it out, so I don't know how well it performs...

```
<?php
$str = preg_split('/[\s,\+]+/', $str); // splits $str into individual words when
                                       // it finds spaces, commas, and/or plus
                                       // signs. This way, you won't have to
                                       // force users to use plus signs
$fields = array('field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4');
foreach ($keywords as $i => $keyword) {
    // escapes and quotes those keywords to prevent against injection attack
    $keywords[$i] = '"' . mysql_real_escape_string($keyword) . '"';
}
// concatenates the keywords into one string that we can use as a set in
// MySQL's IN() clause
$keywords = implode(',', $keywords);
$fieldSearchQueries = array ();
foreach ($fields as $thisField) {
    // here's the IN() clause, checking each field against the set of keywords
    $fieldSearchqueries[] = 'CASE WHEN ' . $thisField . ' IN (' . $keywords . ')'
        . ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END';
}
$query = 'SELECT *, ' . implode(' + ' $fieldSearchQueries) . ' AS rank '
    . 'FROM TABLE WHERE rank > 0 ORDER BY rank';
?>
```

This should create a query something like this:

```
SELECT *,
    CASE WHEN field1 IN ('India', 'Rainfall', 'English') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    + CASE WHEN field2 IN ('India', 'Rainfall', 'English') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    + CASE WHEN field3 IN ('India', 'Rainfall', 'English') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    + CASE WHEN field4 IN ('India', 'Rainfall', 'English') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    AS rank
FROM TABLE
WHERE rank > 0
ORDER BY rank
```

I just learned about `CASE WHEN` today, from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108187/sql-find-rows-and-sort-according-to-number-of-matching-columns#answer-2108421) which is about an almost identical problem. The way I've set it up, it should return 1 if `field1` is in the keywords, then add 1 if `field2` is in the keywords, and so on. This gives you `rank`, a new field that you can sort by. The original answerer says it's not very efficient, though, so you might want to check out the other solutions on that page as well.

Comment: For `CASE` statements that simply choose between one of two values, `IF()` is even easier: `IF(field1 in (...), 1, 0) + IF(field2 in (...), 1, 0) + ...`

Comment: Oh nice! Thanks for the info. Do you know if it's more efficient at all? (To be honest, I don't know in what way `CASE WHEN` is inefficient; I just got that comment from the answer I linked to :-)

Comment: Honestly; I have no idea which is more efficient.  It probably doesn't even matter that much; I just tend to prefer the less verbose option.

Comment: @BharatMaheshwari there might be a typo in your SQL -- the column `rank` is created in the SQL query itself by giving a name to the value created by adding up the results of all those `CASE WHEN` statements.

Comment: this is working superb. but it has a drawback for example i'm searching with single keyword "bumper" and i have columns of items in which there are items like "front bumper" , "back bumper" , "small bumper". it should return these results but it shows 0 result. `SELECT *, ( CASE WHEN oem_part_no IN ('bumper') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN brand IN ('bumper') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN item IN ('bumper') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN vehicle IN ('bumper') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN make IN ('bumper') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS rank FROM items having rank >0 ORDER BY rank DESC`

Comment: @kabir if you're doing fuzzy search that's a little different; the original question/answer dealt with exact value-to-value matches. You'd want something like `CASE WHEN oem_part_no LIKE '%bumper%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`. If you've got multiple search terms it'll get more complicated still.

Comment: @Pauld'Aoust you are right, but  i'm looking for code which gives value to value matches as top result but in case we don't find any value to value match then it should show related result using keywords. this code  `CASE WHEN oem_part_no LIKE '%bumper%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` this is good for single keyword but not applicable on multiple keywords

Comment: @kabir that's true, as I mentioned in my comment. Sounds like you'll need something a bit more complicated -- how about using `CASE WHEN field1 = 'bumper' THEN 2 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN field1 LIKE '%bumper%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` for each field you're searching against? That'd make exact matches have double the ranking of fuzzy matches. Then duplicate those two `CASE`s for each keyword, and then duplicate the whole thing for each field you're searching against. At this stage the query is getting quite verbose, but you'll get a decent relevance search.

Comment: @Pauld'Aoust thanx man i used both things and its working awesome. yes  its become complicated to understand the code to others ;) but its match my requirement