# Find all the rows given the number of matching attributes and the query

Tags: algorithm, matching, categorical-data

Below is my problem definition:

Given a database D, each row has m categorical attributes. Given a query which is a vector of m categorical attributes and the number of matching, k. How to find all the row ids such that the number of matching attributes to the query is greater than or equal to k efficiently?

The easier version (I think) is that given a vector of <=m-categorical attributes, how to find ids of all the rows that match those <=m-categorical attributes.

In some of the question (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108187/sql-find-rows-and-sort-according-to-number-of-matching-columns)), they need to scan the whole database every time the query comes in. I think this is not fast enough. I am not sure about the complexity on this actually.

If it is possible, I want to avoid scanning all the rows in the database. Therefore, I am thinking of building some kinds of index but I am wondering if there is any existing work for these?

In addition, is there a problem similar to this and what is it called? I want to take a look.

Thank you very much for your help.

(Regarding the coding, I mainly code in Python 2.7 for this.)