# Is there a MySQL query to find best match of multiple fields?

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

Is there a way to create a MySQL query to find best matches from table? Lets say that i have a table called users. Each user has different skills/qualities e.g has_driving_licence, has_own_car, age and height. From client i want to send a user search request with following body:

```
    {
      "has_driving_licence": true,
      "has_own_car": true,
      "age": 25,
      "height": 180
    }
```

What i want to do is send a response of users that matches with all of these fields and lets say users that are missing two of these qualities. So i could display results in client like "Hey, here is all the users that matches with your requirements and here is some users that quite don't match".

Example of users table:

```
| id   | has_driving_licence | has_own_car | age | height |
+------+---------------------+-------------+-----+--------+
|    1 | true                | true        | 25  | 180    |
|    2 | false               | false       | 30  | 190    |
|    3 | true                | false       | 25  | 180    |
|    4 | true                | false       | 25  | 170    |
+------+---------------------+-------------+-----+--------+
```

After the query expected result would be array of users:

```
    [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "has_driving_licence": true,
        "has_own_car": true,
        "age": 25,
        "height": 180
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "has_driving_licence": true,
        "has_own_car": false, <-- Not a match
        "age": 25,
        "height": 180
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "has_driving_licence": true,
        "has_own_car": false, <-- Not a match
        "age": 25,
        "height": 170 <-- Not a match
      }
    ]
```

So what i would like to know that is there a way to do this by MySQL query or do i need to create queries to get all possible results or just select all and try to combine those results?

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected result  ( add the sample as  tabular text)

Comment: See [SQL : find rows and sort according to number of matching columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2108187). As a sidenote: "age" isn't the best value to store, since it will get less and less accurate the longer you are using the database. Maybe store the birthday/year instead.

Comment: That looks like something i am looking for. I know that age should not be stored like that but it is just an example and it's not the point of this question. Thanks!